# Determinar propriedade CSS com base em uma condição em javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5, javascript-eventos

**HTML**

```
<tr class="linha">
 <td class="tipoMov">Receita</td>
 <td>Corte de cabelo</td>
 <td>R$20,00</td>
</tr>
```

**Javascript**

```
window.onload = function(){
 if(document.getElementsByClassName("tipoMov").innerHTML == 'Receita'){
   document.getElementsByClassName("linha").style.backgroundColor = "#90EE90";
 }
}
```

O que eu preciso é alterar o background-color da tag "tr" conforme o que estiver na tag "td" com classe "tipoMov".

Quando eu coloco o getElementById ao invés de getElementsByClassName funciona, porém eu tenho várias linhas, então não daria para usar o ID, preciso usar class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É basicamente como o amigo falou na outra resposta, mas você pode fazer de oura forma usando `querySelector(".tipoMov")`. Ao percorrer cada linha da tabela, o querySelector irá buscar o elemento com a classe `.tipoMov` e pegar o texto dentro dele e comparar se é igual a `Receita`. Se for igual, aplicará a cor de fundo:

```js
const linha = document.getElementsByClassName("linha");
for(let i of linha){
   if(i.querySelector(".tipoMov").textContent.trim() == "Receita"){
      i.style.backgroundColor = "#90EE90";
   }
}
```

```html
<table border="1">
<tr class="linha">
 <td class="tipoMov">Receita</td>
 <td>Corte de cabelo</td>
 <td>R$20,00</td>
</tr>
<tr class="linha">
 <td class="tipoMov">Outra coisa</td>
 <td>Corte de cabelo</td>
 <td>R$20,00</td>
</tr>
<tr class="linha">
 <td class="tipoMov">Receita</td>
 <td>Corte de cabelo</td>
 <td>R$20,00</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Veja que utilizei `.trim()` para eliminar possíveis espaços nas bordas do texto. Isso porque se você indentar o texto dentro da `td`, o texto irá retornar com espaços antes e depois dele.

Por exemplo, se você fizer assim:

```
<td class="tipoMov">
   Receita
</td>
```

A palavra `Receita` virá com espaços, porque o HTML considera novas linhas como um espaço em branco.

Answer (score 1):

A função `getElementsByClassName` retorna vários resultados enquanto o `getElementById` retorna apenas um.

Para funcionar com o `getElementsByClassName` você deve percorrer a lista e alterar item a item.

```
window.onload = function(){
    const elementosHTML = document.getElementsByClassName("tipoMov")
    for(elemento of elementosHTML) {
        if(elemento.innerHTML == 'Receita'){
            elemento.style.backgroundColor = "#90EE90";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No caso o elemento que eu quero mudar o background é o de classe "linha", dessa forma o background que foi alterado foi o de classe "tipoMov"